# How to create custom appender for log4j2 in spring

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, appender

Modifed based on the suggestion, so now when I tried to run the app, the append() function inside MyCustomAppender is still not called at all although I trigged the log.error in the main application. Maybe something I missed?
Is this a spring issue? I put break point in the MyCustomAppender, nothing got called at all.

Thanks

Below is original question:

I have googled a lot for creating custom appender for log4j2 as I need to handle log information and send over to our log server, I googled a lot, nothing worked, this is what I did and hope to have your suggestion on where is the error.

```
package demo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginAttribute;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;

@Plugin(category = "Core", name = "MyCustomAppender")
public class MyCustomAppender extends AbstractAppender {

    protected MyCustomAppender(String name, Filter filter,
            Layout<? extends Serializable> layout) {
        super(name, filter, layout);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static MyCustomAppender createAppender(
            @PluginAttribute("name") String name) {
        // note: in this example the class name matches the @Plugin name,
        // but this is not required.
        return new MyCustomAppender(name, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void append(LogEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("inside here 123");
    }

}
```

And this is log4j2.xml in spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- status = level of INTERNAL Log4j events that should be logged to the console, used to debug log4j itself -->
<Configuration status="TRACE" packages="demo">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="PID">????</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] log4j2%X{context} - ${sys:PID} %5p [%t] --- %c{1}: %m%n</Property>
        <!-- Default logging level, can override with system property: -DlogLevel=xxx -->
        <Property name="EXEC_SVC_LOGLEVEL">info</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
       <MyCustomAppender name="ABC"/>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="ABC" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Now when I run the main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoLoggerApplication {
        //private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.warn("This is information!");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoLoggerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I hope the warning message can trigger the append() method inside the myCustomAppender class, but never happened.

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please close it.

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration has `<Configuration status="WARN" packages="demo">`, but is your `MyCustomAppender` in package "demo"? To rephrase, is the fully qualified class name of your custom appender `demo.MyCustomAppender`?

If not, put the correct package name of your custom appender in the `<Configuration packages="CORRECT-PACKAGE-HERE">` package attribute.

Secondly, you declared the name of your custom plugin to be "MyCustomAppender" (in `@Plugin(category = "Core", name = "MyCustomAppender")`). However, your configuration refers to an unknown `<StubAppender name="ABC"/>`. Replace StubAppender with `<MyCustomAppender name="ABC"/>`.

To help with troubleshooting, you can set the internal log4j status log level to TRACE in your configuration: `<Configuration status="TRACE"...` This will show internal log4j log messages on the console. For example, unknown plugins like StubAppender should generate an error message here.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Plugin(name = "MyCustomAppender", category = Node.CATEGORY, elementType = "appender", printObject = true)
```

you need to change the annotation like this.

Don't forget to add the configuration in log4j2.xml as below

```
<Configuration packages="yourAppenderPackageName">
```

Answer (score 0):

I double checked my pom file, and it is error there. I have to put

```
<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

inside spring-boot, thanks